# Elment Plus + Vue3 js table with dynamic table columns , input box inside the table

Tags: dynamic, vuejs3, v-for, v-model, element-plus

[the actual display of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm6MT.png)

Got problems with data-binding under such circumstance. Input boxes from the whole row seems to be recognizede as one.

```
<h2>Vue3 + Element plus Dyanamic table</h2>
<el-table :data="tableData" style="width: 100%">
  <el-table-column
      :prop="index"
      :label="item"
      v-for="(item, index) in tableHeader"
      :key="index"
  >
    <template v-slot="scope">
      <el-input :name="item" v-model="scope.row.index"></el-input>
    </template>
  </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

```
 data() {
return {
  tableHeader: {
    1: "Name",
    2: "Birthday",
    3: "Address",
    4: "Age",
    5: "Tel",
  },
  tableData: [{
    1:'',
    2:'',
    3:'',
    4:'',
    5:'',
  }, {
    1:'',
    2:'',
    3:'',
    4:'',
    5:'',
  }]
```

I'm trying to load the table header(namely the number of the columns and each column's name) from back-end data. Input boxes is the main feature in this table. And i want to store the data fram input boxes into tableData and then send it back to back-end.How could i fix this?

Comment: Would be good to know your `tableHeader` and `tableData`. Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for notice ,i've alrealy added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a very basic [Element+ Table](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/table.html) from the Docs.

The way you are trying to bind `props` to `index` does not make sense to me.

```
<template>
  <el-table :data="tableData" stripe style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column prop="date" label="Date" width="180" />
    <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" width="180" />
    <el-table-column prop="address" label="Address" />
  </el-table>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const tableData = [
  {
    date: '2016-05-03',
    name: 'Tom',
    address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles',
  },
  {
    date: '2016-05-02',
    name: 'Tom',
    address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles',
  },
  {
    date: '2016-05-04',
    name: 'Tom',
    address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles',
  },
  {
    date: '2016-05-01',
    name: 'Tom',
    address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles',
  },
]
</script>
```

Comment: No, I wanna insert input boxes into the table and the header of this table must come from dyanamic backend data which is not pre-determined. That's why i'm trying to bind prop with index. However, it didn't work